# Quando usar o atributo xmlns no elemento html?

Tags: html5

Na HTML5, quando usar o atributo xmlns? Obrigada!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
      ...
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No seu exemplo, `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` indica que a sintaxe utilizada no documento é na verdade **XHTML5** e não **HTML5**.

As linhas seguintes criam diversos *namespaces* **XML**, usados para definir suas próprias tags. Exemplo: tendo `xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"` você poderia ter tags no seu documento da seguinte forma:

```
<h:pessoa>
    <h:nome>NOME</h:nome>
    <h:idade>IDADE</h:idade>
</h:pessoa>
```

onde a definição das tags `<h:...>` é dada em `http://java.sun.com/jsf/html`.

**Resumindo:**

Se você estiver servindo apenas documentos puramente em formato **HTML5**, utilize o padrão:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!-- sua página -->
</html>
```

Mas se você quiser servir documentos com formato **XHTML5**, então é necessário incluir o atributo `xmlns` na tag html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <!-- sua página -->
</html>
```

[As diferenças entre o HTLM5 e o HTML4<sup>en</sup>](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#syntax) podem ser úteis.